# Installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, apt-get

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails using RVM. I am following this guide

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

I have just installed RVM, and used rvm install 1.9.2, but when I try to run ruby -v, I get this error

```
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

I am not sure whether or not to install ruby using apt-get. The tutorial mentions to avoid using apt-get when installing ruby and stuff. Also, I installed ruby on RVM. I am confused, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you do `rvm install 1.9.2`, you need to tell RVM to use that installed version of Ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

To make this the default:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

You may need to do a `source ~/.bashrc` to update the changes, or even reboot/logout (Ubuntu sometimes doesn't fully reload everything until a complete reboot).

Comment: Did you add the appropriate line to the end of your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` file? And did you restart your terminal session and/or reboot after doing so (to make sure `bash` reads in the contents of `.bashrc`)?

Comment: I reloaded the .bashrc file and nothing happened, then tried rebooting ubuntu, it now works! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try opening another terminal or run source .bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

When you installed RVM, did you remember to add this line to your ~/.bash_profile and reload your shell?

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: tried appending the line to .bash_profile, also added a line to .bashrc, still having the same error..

Comment: @pny, You don't need it in both places, just one. Look through both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` to determine whether one calls the other, and to determine which is the appropriate file. I usually go with `~/.bashrc` but your mileage might vary.